# I need to generate a hex file for Arduino in Linux

Tags: 17.10, gcc, arduino

I bricked my BIOS and the one method which can help me to resolve the problem is to flash the BIOS chip via Arduino or other programmer.

I need to generate a hex file in Linux for Arduino to make it. I need to install `flashrom` and `gcc` compiler for `avr`.

I'm using UbuntU 17.10 from disc and it is not installed, because I didn't know how to do it.

**Is this possible with this disc to make all this things?**

I haven't any experience with linux.

edited:

I have problem with the installation, I trying to make it with the console but nothing is not like all tutorials. Is this because I using portable disk with Ubuntu?

Comment: I have problem with the installation, I trying to make  it with the console but nothing is not like all tutorials. Is this because I using portable disk with ubuntu?

Comment: Please don't add additional information as comment but rather edit your question and add it there.